# AlarmManager: бесконечная работа

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Ребята, у меня стоит следующая задача: выполнять определённую задачу каждые 15 минут.

Я пробовал использовать сервис, в котором использовал обычный Timer

```
public void myTimer(){
    Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
        @Override
        public void run() {
            push();
        }
    }, 1L*10000, 1L * 10000); // 600 миллисекунд до первого запуска,1800
}
```

Но сервис, штука не постоянная, она может работать, потом может из-за нехватки памяти закрыться и прекратить работу.

Прорыл весь интернет и понял, что могу попробовать выполнять данную задачу с помощью AlarmManager.

Вопрос: как мне сделать бесконечный будильник(AlarmManager), чтобы после первого запуска приложения поставился будильник, который будет выполнять задачу через 15 минут и заново ставить себя на это же время. Так получится бесконечный цикл.

Насколько я понял,то будильник не убивается после перезагрузки телефона или отключения интернета.

Comment: Здесь смотрели: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Если поможет, то вот

**Ресивер для старта**

```
public class OnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context, RepeatedWork.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gpsTrackerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int intervalInMinutes = 5;
        Boolean currentlyTracking = true;

        if (currentlyTracking) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    intervalInMinutes * 60000, // 60000 = 1 minute,
                    pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

**Вызываемый ресивер**

```
public class RepeatedWork extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Запускаем
        LocationService.enqueueWork(context.getApplicationContext(), new Intent());
    }

}
```

**Сервис**

```
public class LocationService extends JobIntentService {

    static final int JOB_ID = 1;
    static final String TAG = "Job Service";

    public DBHelper dbHelper;

    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, LocationService.class, JOB_ID, work);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        int TotalRunning = 30; // Количество операций

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalRunning; i++) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Running service " + (i + 1)
                    + "/" + TotalRunning + " @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            try {


                // Выполняем операцию
                ..................

                Thread.sleep(10000); // 10 секунд задержка
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Выполняем операцию по завершению
        ...............

        Log.i(TAG, "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }
}
```

**Манифест**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.system_gps.glonass">

    <!-- Отключает спящий -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <!-- Автозапуск приложения при загрузке -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <!-- Разрешение на использование интернета -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Boot.OnBoot"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver.RepeatedWork">
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".Services.LocationService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

> android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"

Единственный момент, не могу победить когда устройство входит в спящий режим., на некоторых устройствах отрубается AlarmManager

Comment: Вот у меня тоже похожая проблема. Использую сейчас AlarmManager и так же через минут 10 спокойного режима перестаёт работать

Comment: shcherbuk - Получилось ли найти решение?

Comment: нет. Сейчас работаю с Firebase Job, но всё равно не стабильная работа. Может работать может нет. Уже без понятия что использовать. Попробовал почти всё

Comment: Я сообщу как найду варианты, пока другим занимаюсь.